# Status bar color change event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar

My question is simple. In the Android API is there any kind of event that is triggered when the status bar's color changes? If not, anyone has any ideas how to accomplish this? Root access is available but obviously it would be better to not use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no API for this as far as I'm aware. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am working on a app that adds round corners to the device. It is working properly, the black overlays are being added. Although I wanted to also add overlays on the top of the app (when the status bar ends and the app starts). Obviously I want to add overlays in the same color then the status bar.

Comment: *that the | sorry